# UIHint does not work with IList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, data-annotations, partial-views

I have a property in my **ViewMode**:

```
[UIHint("FileUpload")]
public IList<string> Images { get; set; }
```

In view **Create.cshtml**

```
@html.ValidationSummary(true)
@html.EditorForModel()
```

In the folder `Shared/EditorTemplates/FileUpload.cshtml`

```
<h3>Test</h3>
```

But the field is not displayed. Simply, nothing happens!

I did the same test with another type of field and it worked:

```
[UIHint("FileUpload")]
public string Test { get; set; }
```

What could be wrong?
How do you solve this problem?

If I manually add the code below in my **Create.cshtml** view, it works!

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Images)
```

I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `UIHint` doesn't work with lists. You will need a loop inside the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/FileUpload.cshtml`). The UIHint template is passed the model which in this case is a `IList<string>`.

```
@model IList<string>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: But why if I manually put the code `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Images)` on view it works!? I think the problem is not with the `UIHint` but with `@Html.EditorForModel();`  Otherwise the code `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Images)` would not work

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa, if you use `@Html.EditorForModel()` you could define a custom editor template for the given view model (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`) where you could use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Images)`. In fact it is possible that EditorForModel doesn't recurse into sub editor templates.